# python if statement printing incorrect condition

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone please assist me with what i am doing wrong here?

```
  root@localhost:$ cat Names
                   This is Paul
```

This is my python script

```
from subprocess import *
test = check_output("grep Paul Names", stderr=STDOUT, shell=True )

if test is True :
  print ("Correct")
else:
  print("Incorrect")
```

Result

```
 root@localhost:$ python find.py
                  Incorrect
```

This should print correct.

Comment: `if test:` although it would be better named `output`

Comment: my two cents: is that your check_output is wrong. I'd ignore self because it will do what you want, but may not be appropriate in certain conditions, which you can look up.

Comment: Hint: The result of `check_output` isn't a boolean. Try printing it to the screen or checking its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `is` is an *identity* operator, so it is not performing the comparison you *think* it is. It compares to see if you are pointing to the same object.

Your check should simply be:

```
if test:
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thank you.

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo `test is True` is a very bad idea: it will be false unless test is set to `True` specifically. `if bool(test) is True` is valid, although unpythonic.

Answer (score 2):

Variable `test` will contains the stdout genrated by the command.
Look at this example:

```
from subprocess import *
test = check_output("echo test", stderr=STDOUT, shell=True )
assert test == 'test\n'
```

To test if a variable is an empty you could just do:

```
if test:
```

where `test=''` will fail and `test='anything else'` will pass.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the intention of the code is to print "Correct" if "Paul" is found in the file, and "Incorrect" otherwise.

Even if you replace `if test is True:` with `if test:`, your code will not work in the case where "Paul" is *not* found in the file. In this case, `check_output` will raise a `subprocess.CalledProcessError` because the exit code of grep is nonzero.

Instead, you could use `subprocess.call` and check the exit code of grep directly. Use `stdout=PIPE` to suppress the output of grep.

```
from subprocess import *
exit_code = call("grep Paul Names", stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
if exit_code == 0:
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put check_output in a `try-except` block since if the named file ain't present in file system, subprocess throws error. Catch it and manipulate properly

```
from subprocess import *
try:
    test = check_output("grep a ax.py", shell=True )
    if test:
        print("correct")
    else:
        print("incorrect")
except CalledProcessError as err:
    print(err)
```